# WooCommerce subscription, give option to prorate or not to prorate to user while switching subscription

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, subscription

With WooCommerce subscription plugin, user can switch between subscriptions. And there is an option in the backend to prorate the recurring payment. When the option prorate option is enabled, and user switch subscription the payment is made right there. It does not wait for current subscription period to end. To make the switch happen after the current subscription end, the option needs to be disabled.

My problem is that I need to have these both options in the frontend for the user to select when they try to switch subscription. For eg, user needs to have

- an option to switch subscription ‘right now’
- and another option to wait for the current subscription to end

The documentation for the WooCommerce subscription does not have much in prorate feature. Have anyone done the same ? how can it be done programmatically, with filters etc ?

Thx

Comment: Did you found any solution for this problem?